# S3 object (public URL ) to Google cloud storage programmatically using JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, file-transfer, gsutil

Want to do transfer of files from AWS S3 (Public URL available) to Google cloud storage programmatically using Java .

Each S3 file is auto generated by Third party and URLs are provided on daily basis. Inorder to have complete access to this data i want to transfer those files to our Google cloud storage for further analysis.

Can not create transfer job at scheduled time since the S3 URLs are random and will be known to us on daily retrieval .

I am unable to find any code related to gsutil in java.

Comment: please add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google libraries like in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program). In order to begin transfering data you would firstly need to create a transfer job. The transfer job manages and coordinates your data transfer. You can create the transfer job from the Google Cloud Console, as documented  [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-jobs#create-transfer), or you can do it programatically as below :

```
package com.google.cloud.storage.storagetransfer.samples;

import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.Storagetransfer;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.AwsAccessKey;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.AwsS3Data;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.Date;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.GcsData;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.Schedule;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.TimeOfDay;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.TransferJob;
import com.google.api.services.storagetransfer.v1.model.TransferSpec;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * Creates a one-off transfer job from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage.
 */
public final class AwsRequester {
  /**
   * Creates and executes a request for a TransferJob from Amazon S3 to Cloud Storage.
   *
   * <p>The {@code startDate} and {@code startTime} parameters should be set according to the UTC
   * Time Zone. See:
   * https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storagetransfer/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storagetransfer/v1/model/Schedule.html#getStartTimeOfDay()
   *
   * @return the response TransferJob if the request is successful
   * @throws InstantiationException
   *           if instantiation fails when building the TransferJob
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   *           if an illegal access occurs when building the TransferJob
   * @throws IOException
   *           if the client failed to complete the request
   */
  public static TransferJob createAwsTransferJob(
      String projectId,
      String jobDescription,
      String awsSourceBucket,
      String gcsSinkBucket,
      String startDate,
      String startTime,
      String awsAccessKeyId,
      String awsSecretAccessKey)
      throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
    Date date = TransferJobUtils.createDate(startDate);
    TimeOfDay time = TransferJobUtils.createTimeOfDay(startTime);
    TransferJob transferJob =
        new TransferJob()
            .setDescription(jobDescription)
            .setProjectId(projectId)
            .setTransferSpec(
                new TransferSpec()
                    .setAwsS3DataSource(
                        new AwsS3Data()
                            .setBucketName(awsSourceBucket)
                            .setAwsAccessKey(
                                new AwsAccessKey()
                                    .setAccessKeyId(awsAccessKeyId)
                                    .setSecretAccessKey(awsSecretAccessKey)))
                    .setGcsDataSink(new GcsData().setBucketName(gcsSinkBucket)))
            .setSchedule(
                new Schedule()
                    .setScheduleStartDate(date)
                    .setScheduleEndDate(date)
                    .setStartTimeOfDay(time))
            .setStatus("ENABLED");

    Storagetransfer client = TransferClientCreator.createStorageTransferClient();
    return client.transferJobs().create(transferJob).execute();
  }

  public static void run(PrintStream out)
      throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
    String projectId = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("projectId");
    String jobDescription = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("jobDescription");
    String awsSourceBucket = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("awsSourceBucket");
    String gcsSinkBucket = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("gcsSinkBucket");
    String startDate = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("startDate");
    String startTime = TransferJobUtils.getPropertyOrFail("startTime");
    String awsAccessKeyId = TransferJobUtils.getEnvOrFail("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
    String awsSecretAccessKey = TransferJobUtils.getEnvOrFail("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");

    TransferJob responseT =
        createAwsTransferJob(
            projectId,
            jobDescription,
            awsSourceBucket,
            gcsSinkBucket,
            startDate,
            startTime,
            awsAccessKeyId,
            awsSecretAccessKey);
    out.println("Return transferJob: " + responseT.toPrettyString());
  }

  /**
   * Output the contents of a successfully created TransferJob.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      run(System.out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some people might be confused by the fact that it is indeed necessary to use a one-off transfer job, in this case, so you might want to explain why that is true.